# Она не зайдет на кухню, пока там ее бывший муж.

Tags: наклонение, сослагательное

Задание: мне надо сравнить использование сослагательного наклонения в двух предложениях.

Первое предложение в оригинале на итальянском. Там в придаточном искользуется глагол в сослагательном наклонении. 
(грубо говоря: ... , пока там [*есть/находится*] ее бывший муж. Вот этот глагол "*есть/находится*" стоит в сослагательном наклонении.

Второе предложение: перевод на русский.

Она не зайдет на кухню, *пока там ее бывший муж*.

Как я понимаю, в этом придаточном времени нет "высказанного" глагола, но он подразумевается в голове.

Я указала в какой временной форме и в каком наклонении стоит итальянский глагол, но не знаю, что написать в русском. Можно сказать, что в этом предложении используется изъявительное наклонение? Или если нет глагола, нет наклонения?

Answer (score 1):

В обеих частях предложения (в главном и придаточном) глаголы стоят в изъявительном наклонении: в первом (в будущем времени,изъявительного наклонения), в придаточном - глагол "находится" (в настоящем времени, изъяв. накл.) опущен, но подразумевается.

Comment: большое спасибо!!! такое радостное чувство внутри, что то как я думала это правильно!!! yuppie yuppie yeah!!! : )

Answer (score 1):

Вы меня окончательно запутали. Пожалуйста, задавайте вопросы более конкретно, отбрасывая ненужную информацию (зачем надо было говорить об итальянском?). Насколько я понял, вас интересует то, чем выражено сказуемое в придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения, и то, к каком наклонению глагол относится (это в вашем задании указано).

> Она не зайдет на кухню, пока там ее бывший муж.

В придаточном предложении мы имеем двусоставную структуру, потому что оба главных члена есть. ***Муж*** — подлежащее, к которому есть определение ***бывший***. А вот со сказуемым всё чуточку сложнее. Оно здесь выражено наречием ***там***. Глагол-связка ***быть, есть*** в русском языке в настоящем времени нулевая (правда, можно иногда использовать ***есть***, но это редко встретишь). Соответственно, грамматическая основа имеет следующий вид: муж (был, будет) там.

Теперь о наклонении. Подразумеваемый глагол-связка ***быть*** в данном случае выражает действие реальное, поэтому наклонение здесь изъявительное. Это вообще очевидно.

И к слову, глагол-связка ***есть*** иногда всё-таки встречается в речи. См. предложения.

> Мы есть люди. Успех есть свобода. Жизнь есть удовольствие.

Comment: ... мне правда очень жаль, что я Вас сержу своим формулированием! понимаю, что у меня получается очень коряво, но я очень очень стараюсь!..

Comment: Насчет этого вообще не переживайте, я нисколько не сержусь.

Comment: Тагрикс, в данном случае ''есть" - это не связка. Это полнозначный глагол.

Comment: [См.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

Comment: "Там ее бывший муж".  Это неполное предложение, сказуемое "находится" пропущено, но его можно восстановить из текста. Наречие "там" не является именной частью сказуемого.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что предложение построено **некорректно:** Она не зайдет на кухню, пока там ее бывший муж.

**Возможные варианты:**

Она не зайдет на кухню, если там находится ее бывший муж (изъявительное наклонение).

Она не зашла бы на кухню, если бы там был ее бывший муж (сослагательное наклонение).